# If any open set is a countable union of balls, does it imply separability?

Tags: gn.general-topology

If a metric space is separable, then any open set is a countable union of balls. Is the converse statement true?

UPDATE1. It is a duplicate of the question here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94280/if-every-open-set-is-a-countable-union-of-balls-is-the-space-separable/94301#94301

UPDATE2. Let me summarize here the positive answer following Joel David Hamkins and Ashutosh. It is a matter of taste, but I omit using ordinals and use Zorn lemma instead, which may be more usual for most mathematicians (at least, it is for me).

Lemma 1. If $(X,d)$ is non-separable metric space, then for some $r>0$ there exists an uncountable subset $X_1\subset X$ such that $d(x,y)>r$ for any two points $x\ne y$ in $X_1$.

Proof. For each $r=1/n$ consider the maximal (by inclusion) subset with such property. If it is countable, then $X$ has a countable $1/n$-net for each $n$, hence it is separable.

Now consider two cases. Define $X_2\subset X_1$ as a set of points $x\in X_1$ for which there exist a point $y_x\in X$ such that $0<d(x,y_x)<r/10$. Consider two cases.

1) $X_2$ is uncountable. Consider the union of open balls $U=\cup_{x\in X_2} B(x,d(x,y_x))$. Consider any open ball $B(z,a)$ containing in $U$. We have $z\in U$, so $d(z,x)<d(x,y_x)$ for some $x$, but $r/5>2d(x,y_x)\geq d(x,z)+d(x,y_x)\geq d(z,y_x)>a$ since $y_x\notin B(z,a)$. It implies that $B(z,a)$ is contained in a unique ball $B(x,d(x,y_x))$, hence we need uncountably many such balls to cover whole $U$.

2) $X_3=X\setminus X_2$ is uncountable. For any $x\in X_3$ define $R(x)>0$ as a radius of maximal at most countable open ball centered in $x$. Clearly $R(x)\geq r/10$ for any $x\in X_3$. For any $x\in X_3$ define a star centered in $x$ as a union $D=x\cup C$, where $C=\{z_1,z_2,\dots\}\subset X_3$ is a countable sequence of points with $d(x,z_i)\rightarrow R(x)+0$. Choose a maximal disjoint subfamily of stars. Clearly it is uncountable, else we may easily increase it. Denote by $U$ the set of centers of chosen stars. It is open (as any subset of $X_3$), assume that it is a countable union of balls $U=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} B(x_i,r_i)$, $x_i\in U$. We have $r_i> R(x_i)$ for some $i$, else $U$ is at most countable. But then $B(x_i,r_i)$ contains infinitely many points of the star $D$ centered in $x_i$, while by our construction $U\cap D=\{x_i\}$. A contradiction.

Comment: A surprising cute question. Perhaps it's more than just cute.

Comment: One could also consider a closely related question, namely a metric space $\ (Y\ d),\ $ and $\ X\subseteq Y$, and traces of balls $\ B(y\ r)\cap X$ for $\ y\in Y\ $ (instead of simply $\ X\ $ and balls in $\ X\ $).

Comment: If we allow exterior centers, the answer becomes obviously no: take arbitrary X, all distances are equal to 1, then for any subset Z of X choose a new point y(Z) with distances 1 to Z and 2 to all other points.

Comment: Are there any clear connections between this question and the Baire Category theorem?

Comment: Andres, comments below suggest that my initial tag set-theory was quite reasonable)

Comment: You can actually comment-notify editors if you want by adding the @ as ususal.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Towards a contradiction, let us assume that we have a metric space $X = \{x_i : i < \omega_1\}$ in which any two points are at least unit distance apart and every subset of $X$ is the union of a countable family of open balls. Let $r_i$ be the supremum of all $r > 0$ such that $B(x_i, r)$ is countable. Construct $\{C_i : i < \omega_1\}$ such that

(1) Each $C_i$ is countable and the infimum of $\{d(x_i, y): y \in C_i\}$ is $r_i$

(2) If $i < j$, then $x_i \notin C_j$

Now let $I \in [\omega_1]^{\omega_1}$ be such that whenever $i < j$, $x_j \notin C_i$. Suppose $Y = \{x_i : i \in I\}$ can be covered by a family $F$ of countably many balls. Let $i \in I$ be least such that $B(x_i, r) \in F$ for some $r > r_i$. Pick $y \in C_i \cap B(x_i, r)$. So $y \in \bigcup F = Y$ so that $y = x_j$ for some $j \in I$ which is impossible.

Comment: Nice conclusion.

Comment: Great! This seems to get rid of the need for any CH assumption in the final case of my argument.

Comment: I don’t understand how this answers the question. If $X$ is a counterexample to the OP, it does contain an uncountable subspace $Y$ whose points are at least a fixed distance apart. Now, any open set $U$ is a countable union of balls in $X$, however their centres may be outside $Y$, hence it doesn’t follow that $U\cap Y$ is a countable union of balls in $Y$.

Comment: Emil, in the final case of my answer, I get uncountably many points of a fixed distance apart, and such that they are isolated as well. So the set Ashutosh constructs is open in the whole space, not just in the subspace. So this argument exactly handles the case where I had used CH.

Comment: Oh, I see. So this is not meant as a standalone answer, but as a replacement of the last part of your (Joel’s) proof? @Ashutosh, I think you should make this clear in the answer.

Comment: (Nice argument, by the way.)

Comment: What does the notation $I \in [\omega_1]^{\omega_1}$ mean? That's the one place where this topologist gets lost.

Comment: @LeeMosher: It means that $I$ is a subset of $\omega_1$ (the one inside the square brackets) of size $\omega_1$ (the one in the superscript). In some contexts you may want to change "size" by "order type" but it doesn´t make a difference here.

Answer (score 43):

The answer is yes.

My original argument made use of the continuum hypothesis, or
actually just the assumption that $2^\omega<2^{\omega_1}$), but
this assumption has now been omitted by the argument of Ashutosh,
which handles the case where I had used that assumption. So no
extra hypothesis is needed.

**Theorem.** If every open set in a metric space is a countable union of balls, then the space is separable.

Proof. Suppose that metric space $X$ is not separable. Let us first build
an $\omega_1$-sequence of points $\langle
x_\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$, such that no $x_\alpha$ is in
the closure of the previous points. This is easy from
non-separability. Start with any $x_0$, and at any countable stage
$\alpha$, you've got countably many points $x_\beta$ for
$\beta<\alpha$, and by assumption this is not dense, so there is
some point $x_\alpha$ not in the closure of the previous points.

Now, we can place a ball $B_{r_\alpha}(x_\alpha)$ of rational
radius $r_\alpha>0$ around $x_\alpha$ not containing any $x_\beta$
for $\beta<\alpha$. (This ball may contain later points, but never
mind about that just yet.) Since we've got uncountably many
$\alpha$, we must have chosen the same radius $r_\alpha$
uncountably often. So let's simply throw out all the other points,
keeping only the points where we had used that fixed radius $r$,
and without loss of generality we reduce to the case where every
$x_\alpha$ has distance at least $r$ to all earlier $x_\beta$. It
follows that the points $x_\alpha$ are all also at least distance
$r$ from the later points as well.

I claim that this violates the assumption that every open set is
the union of countably many balls. Consider first the case where uncountably
many of the $x_\alpha$ are not isolated. We may consider an
open set $U$ consisting of tiny balls around each $x_\alpha$. Specifically, pick $p_\alpha$ within $\frac r4$ of $x_\alpha$, and let $U$ be the union of all $B_{d(x_\alpha,p_\alpha)}(x_\alpha)$. This is an open set and $p_\alpha\notin U$. If a ball $B$ is centered within $\frac r4$ of some $x_\gamma$ and contains some $x_\alpha$ and $x_\beta$, then the radius of $B$ must exceed $\frac r2$, in which case it will contain $p_\gamma$ by an instance of the triangle inequality. So if $U$ is a union of open balls, then each ball contains at most one $x_\alpha$, and so $U$ is not a countable union of open balls.

So we have reduced to the case where we have uncountably many
points $x_\alpha$ that are isolated points in $X$, so that
$B_r(x_\alpha)$ contains only $x_\alpha$ for a fixed rational
$r>0$. In particular, every subset of
$\{x_\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\}$ is open in $X$. This case is
exactly handled by the construction in Ashutosh's argument, which
explains how to build such a set that cannot be a countable union
of balls.

(My original argument handled this case with the assumption that
$2^\omega<2^{\omega_1}$, a consequence of the continuum
hypothesis, by pointing out that there are $2^{\omega_1}$ many
open subsets of $\{x_\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\}$, but only
$\omega_1^\omega=2^\omega=\frak{c}$ many choices of countably many
balls of rational radius. So there are just too many open sets for
them all to be realized as the union of countably many balls.)

So we've got a solution in ZFC, without any extra assumption. QED

Comment: It is not very much important, but in order to construct uncountable set with pairwise distances at least $r$ you may just take the maximal (by inclusion) set with this property for small enough $r$: if for any $r=1/n$ such a maximal set is countable, the space is clearly separable.

Comment: You are right! My argument is more algorithmic, like the proof of Zorn, rather than using Zorn itself.

Comment: I feel that the above Joel's proof is incomplete. The mentioned 1-point sets are open in the respective subspace but not in the whole space. And the centers of the ball should belong to the whole space, not just to the subspace. The given argument is open to an objection in the style of @Fedor's example from his comment under his question (under my comment under that question),

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński In my final case, the points are isolated in the whole space, not just in the set of $x_\alpha$'s, so I don't think your comment is right. And for an open set to be a union of balls, the centers of those balls should be in the open set.

Comment: I meant that in the case one would the extra step (not in the above proof) of considering one open set per each subset of the subspace then one would be exposed to something like @Fedor's example mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Joel, I'll read and think more to see all this clearly. Thank you.

Comment: I did a quick MathSciNet search to see if this result was known. The closest hit I got was a paper by Wacław Sierpiński, "Sur l'inversion du théorème de Bolzano-Weierstrass généralisé," Fund. Math. 34 (1947), 155–156, which shows that if the continuum hypothesis is true, then every nonseparable metric space contains a sequence of subsets with no convergent subsequence. While this result doesn't seem directly relevant to the question at hand, it is sort of interesting that Sierpiński found it necessary to assume CH. So maybe CH is needed here as well, after all.

Comment: Does Sierpinski's argument go through with the weaker assumption that $2^\omega<2^{\omega_1}$?

Comment: Perhaps one can try to build a counterexample under the assumption that $2^\omega=2^{\omega_1}$, which is to say, Luzin's hypothesis.

Comment: For the purpose of forcing a consistent counterexample, one can imagine undertaking a forcing iteration with countable support (or finite support) of length $\omega_2$, so that every countable set of balls is added by some stage. And then...? I'm not sure.

Comment: Joel, it seems you had answered this same question a few years ago http://math.stackexchange.com/a/94301. Perhaps you should remove the CH hypothesis over there too.

Comment: How funny! I totally forgot that!

Comment: So does the slightly different question about Sierpinski's proof now arise: if every nonseparable metric space contains a sequence of subsets with no convergent subsequence, does CH hold?

Comment: Joel, I'm probably being thick, but why must a ball $B_s(x)$ that contains two $x_\alpha$, $x_\beta$ also exclude $p_\alpha$?

Comment: @ToddTrimble I think you are right! I should argue more carefully. Pick $p_\alpha$ within $\frac r4$ of $x_\alpha$, and add the ball $B_{d(x_\alpha,p_\alpha)}(x_\alpha)$ to $U$. If this is a union of balls, and some ball $B$ centered within $\frac r4$ of some $x_\gamma$ contains some $x_\alpha$ and $x_\beta$, then the radius of $B$ must exceed $\frac r2$, in which case it will contain $p_\gamma$ by an instance of the triangle inequality. So if $U$ is a union of open balls, then each ball contains at most one $x_\alpha$, and so $U$ is not a countable union of open balls.

Comment: Ah, very good, Joel -- thanks for looking into this. I had begun recording these arguments in the nLab, and now I'm convinced. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is really a followup to my comment to Joel David Hamkins's answer but it is too long for a comment.  Joel asked if Sierpiński's argument uses the full strength of CH.  It looks to me that it does, but here are the two key paragraphs from his paper so that you can judge for yourself.  He doesn't say what $\Omega$ is but I'm assuming it's the first uncountable ordinal.

> L'espace métrique $M$ étant non séparable, il existe, comme on sait, un nombre positif $d$ et une suite transfinie $\{p_\xi\}_{\xi<\Omega}$ du type $\Omega$ formée de points de $M$ tels que $\varrho(p_\xi,p_\eta)\ge d$ pour $\xi<\eta<\Omega$, $\varrho(p,q)$ désignant la distance des points $p$ et $q$ de $M$.
>
> Or, la famille de toutes les suites infinies de nombres naturels étant de puissance du continu, il résulte de l'hypothèse $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ qu'il existe une suite transfinie du type $\Omega$, $\{s^\xi\}_{\xi<\Omega}$, formée de toutes les suites infinies de nombres naturels.  Soit (pour $\xi<\Omega$) $s^\xi$ la suite infinie de nombres naturels $n_1^\xi,n_2^\xi,n_3^\xi,\ldots$; $k$ étant un nombre naturel donné, désignons par $E_k$ l'ensemble formé de tous les points $p_\xi$, tels que $k\in \{n_1^\xi,n_2^\xi,\ldots\}$.  Je dis que la suite infinie d'ensembles $E_1,E_2,E_3,\ldots$ ne contient aucune sous-suite convergente.  Soit, en effet, $E_{k_1}, E_{k_2},\ldots$ où $k_1<k_2<\cdots$ une sous-suite quelconque de la suite $E_1,E_2,\ldots$  D'après la définition de la suite transfinie $\{s^\xi\}_{\xi<\Omega}$ il existe un nombre ordinal $\alpha<\Omega$, tel que $s^\alpha$ est la suite infinie $k_2, k_4, k_6, \ldots$, donc que $n_i^\alpha=k_{2i}$ pour $i=1,2,\ldots$  Vu que $k_1<k_2<k_3<\cdots$, on a donc $k_{2i}\in\{n_1^\alpha,n_2^\alpha,\ldots\}$ et $k_{2i-1} \notin \{n_1^\alpha,n_2^\alpha,\ldots\}$, donc $p_\alpha\in E_{k_{2i}}$ et $p_\alpha \notin E_{k_{2i-1}}$ pour $i=1,2,\ldots$  La sphère ouverte au centre $p_\alpha$ et au rayon $d$ (qui se réduit évidemment a un seul point $p_\alpha$) contient donc un point commun avec chacun des ensembles $E_{k_2},E_{k_4},E_{k_6},\ldots$ et ne contient aucun point des ensembles $E_{k_1},E_{k_3},E_{k_5},\ldots$  Par conséquent la suite infinie d'ensembles $E_{k_1},E_{k_2},E_{k_3},\ldots$ n'est pas convergente.  La suite $E_1,E_2,\ldots$ ne contient donc aucune sous-suite convergente, c.q.f.d.

Roughly:

Since the metric space $M$ is non-separable, there exist $d > 0$ and a sequence $\{p_\xi\}_{\xi<\omega_{1}}$ of points in $M$ such that  $\varrho(p_\xi,p_\eta)\ge d$ for $\xi<\eta<\omega_{1}$, where $\varrho(x,y)$ is the metric on $M$.

Using CH, list all the sequences $s^\xi, \xi < \omega_{1}$ of natural numbers, $s^\xi = \langle n_1^\xi,n_2^\xi,n_3^\xi,\ldots\rangle$; for a given $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $E_k$ be the set of all $p_\xi$ such that $k\in \{n_1^\xi,n_2^\xi,\ldots\}$.  I claim that the sequence  $E_1,E_2,E_3,\ldots$ does not contain any convergent subsequence. For, if $E_{k_1}, E_{k_2},\ldots$ where $k_1<k_2<\cdots$ is an arbitrary subsequence of $E_1,E_2,\ldots$, then there exists $\alpha<\omega_{1}$, such that $s^\alpha$ is the sequence $k_2, k_4, k_6, \ldots$, and so $n_i^\alpha=k_{2i}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$  Since $k_1<k_2<k_3<\cdots$, it follows $k_{2i}\in\{n_1^\alpha,n_2^\alpha,\ldots\}$ and $k_{2i-1} \notin \{n_1^\alpha,n_2^\alpha,\ldots\}$, so $p_\alpha\in E_{k_{2i}}$ and $p_\alpha \notin E_{k_{2i-1}}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots$  The open ball with centre $p_\alpha$ and radius $d$ (which is actually just the singleton $p_\alpha$) intersects each of $E_{k_2},E_{k_4},E_{k_6},\ldots$ non-trivially but is disjoint from  $E_{k_1},E_{k_3},E_{k_5},\ldots$  Consequently, $E_{k_1},E_{k_2},E_{k_3},\ldots$ is not convergent.  So the sequence $E_1,E_2,\ldots$ contains no convergent subsequence, q.e.d.

Comment: Thanks very much! But is there any chance to translate, for those of us whose French is weak?

Comment: Added a rough translation of Sierpinski's argument in Timothy's answer.